# PartialView displays property names instead of property values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I'm learning `MVC`, (so please do not get mad if this is very easy problem) and trying to use `PartialView` that will be commonly used among different pages to display some constant information, but it seems to me that I'm doing something wrong here.

This is hierarchy of my app:

```
Controller
   -AccountController.cs
Models
   -CompanyModel.cs
Views
    Shared
       -Company.cshtml
```

I have a Login view, which is the first that gets loaded.
In Login action I initialize the Model to be used and referenced in my  `PartialView`.

Here is the Login action defined in my AccountController

```
public ActionResult Login()
{
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     CompanyModel cm = new CompanyModel();
     cm.CompanyName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CompanyName"];
     cm.AppName = " - " + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppName"];
     cm.AppVersion = " " + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppVersion"];
     sb.Append("Web Security Administration Portal");
     ViewBag.Message = sb.ToString();
     return View();       
}
```

This is the model:

```
public class CompanyModel
{
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string AppName { get; set; }
    public string AppVersion { get; set; }
}
```

This is the partial view named "Company":

```
@model WebSecurityAdmin.Models.CompanyModel

<table>
   <tr>
      <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CompanyName)
          @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AppName)
          @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AppVersion)
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

This is one of the views, let's say Default view where I want to embed my partial view:

```
@section featured {
<section class="featured">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <hgroup class="title">
            <h1>@Html.Partial("Company")</h1>
        </hgroup>
    </div>
</section>
```

}

When I display Default view I get property names of CompanyModel displayed instead of their values:

```
CompanyName AppName AppVersion
```

Why is that and please explain what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Did you forget to pass `cm` to `View` method as in `return View(cm);`

Comment: FWIW, it's a very bad idea to have your partial view rely on a model that has to be set in the main view's action. Use child actions in this scenario so that you can actually pass the model directly to the partial in a separate context, while your main view can utilize whatever model it needs to.

Comment: But in this way model is going to be passed to Login view, not to Company view?

Answer (score 2):

`@Html.DisplayNameFor()` is what's wrong. That displays either the name of the property, or the name you've given it through an attribute. Instead of that, just have your row like this:

```
<td>
    @model.CompanyName  
    @model.AppName  
    @model.AppVersion  
</td>
```

**Edited**: Adding `@` before `model`

Another option is to use the helper `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.CompanyName)` as depending on the type of property, especially ones more complex than a string or number, will utilize display templates and add large blocks of HTML in a very succinct manner that keeps your Razor view more readable.

Comment: Thanks Anderson for fixing my brain fart as I ran off to my meeting.

Comment: `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.CompanyName)` will also work. For these particular properties, it probably doesn't matter which approach you choose, but if you're dealing with something like a DateTime, you might want `Html.DisplayFor` instead of just outputting it directly.

Comment: @ChrisPratt It all depends on how you have your model set up. I usually avoid the HTML helpers.

Comment: @krillgar You're welcome! Just added the explanation on the answer because SO wouldn't let me edit just for adding 3 characters.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that `DisplayFor` brings in the topic of display templates. Which can render very complex blocks of HTML in a succinct way. Again, doesn't matter in this particular narrow instance, but there's sometimes definite benefits to using `DisplayFor` over just utilizing the property directly.